# why in React Title component re-renders twice on button click?

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering an issue in my React app where the Title component is re-rendering twice when I click on a button in my App component. The Title component is a simple functional component, and I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here's the relevant part of my Title component:

```
import React from 'react';

function Title({ title }: { title: string }) {
  console.log('Title ~ title:', title);
  return <>{title}</>;
}

export default Title;
```

And here's the App component:

```
import Title from './components/Title';
import { ICard } from './modals';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [selectedCardBody, setSelectedCardBody] = useState<ICard | null>(null);
  const cardData: ICard[] = [
    { name: 'test 1', body: 'my name is test 1' },
    { name: 'test 2', body: 'my name is test 2' },
  ];

  const onClickButton = (obj: ICard) => {
    setSelectedCardBody(obj);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Title title='React essentials' />
      {cardData.map((card, index) => (
        <button key={index} onClick={() => onClickButton(card)}>
          {index}
        </button>
      ))}
      {selectedCardBody && selectedCardBody.body}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now whenever I click on the button from App.tsx, I am getting two console logs in the title component. Any insights on why the Title component might be re-rendering twice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You use `selectedCardBody` property in App.tsx: `{selectedCardBody && selectedCardBody.body}`. That's one.

And in the click handler you also assign the property. That's two usages.

Because `selectedCardBody` is part of the state of the `App` component, App will rerender on the state change. The rerender will reinitialize the state.

Comment: Even after excluding the line "{selectedCardBody && selectedCardBody.body}," I still encounter the console appearing twice.

Comment: The `console.log()` is inside the render function of the `Title` component. There are two instances of `<Title/>` in your App component. So the click will cause a re-render of `<App/>` which renders two `<Title />` components.